# no virtual method newJsonReader in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, retrofit2, gson

Im trying to introduce retrofit 2 to my existing app in eclipse.
These are the imported libs:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4gHZz.png)
Okhttp shows fetched body correctly.
And this is the error im getting in onFailure callback:

```
06-22 10:30:18.534: D/Test(5291): No virtual method    
newJsonReader(Ljava/io/Reader;)Lcom/google/gson/stream/JsonReader; 
in class Lcom/google/gson/Gson; or its super classes (declaration of  
'com.google.gson.Gson' appears in /data/app/com.nsrdoc.json-1/base.apk)
```

Help appreciated